# Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I got a flutter project to complete from my friend.

I am using Android Studio(AS) as editor. I have installed flutter and dart plugins in AS. Now, I have imported the flutter project by selecting option at start of AS import AS project. Then it I don't know why it shown me error message to setup Dart SDK(Q1: my first question is why it is giving error I already have dart plugin). Somehow I managed to get Dart from [this link](http://www.gekorm.com/dart-windows/) and gave path to till dart-sdk folder as seen in screenshot
[image]
And now I am stuck on this error:

```
Because xxo_tag_xxxls depends on flutter_test any from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available), version solving failed.
```

Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`.

[image]

Comment: did you install flutter plugin to android studio?

Comment: @PraneethDhanushkaFernando yes, both dart and flutter plugin is installed. I already mentioned it in my question my friend. Please read again Q.

Comment: I recommend you to use [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) It's easy to setup and has a less resources consumption because Android Studio has a plenty of features that you do not use when working with Flutter.

Answer (score 13):

you should configure in addition to the Dart language SDK, pointing to the Flutter SDK ('C:\src\flutter') within your Andoid Studio project. Go to the top menu 'Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean' and the IDE will ask you to configure what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

in mac if you are using android studio, go to android studio at the top left, preferences, flutter, then add path to sdk

Answer (score -1):

you have to configure in addition to the Dart language SDK, pointing to the Flutter SDK ('C:\src\flutter') within your Andoid Studio project. Go to the top menu 'Tools > Flutter >flutter package get and click on it  ,it will find the things those are missing.